# Cleaning up a csv by delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I have a csv file where the columns are all in one row, encased in quotation marks and separated by commas. The columns are in one line.

The rows in the csv are split by comma , if there are 2 commas this means that there is a missing value. I would like to separate these columns by these parameters. In cases where the row has a quotation mark this the comma in the quotation mark should not be a separator because this is an address.

This is a sample of the data (its a csv, I converted it into a dictionary to show you a sample)

```
{'Store code,"Biz","Add","Labels","TotalSe","DirectSe","DSe","TotalVe","SeVe","MaVe","Totalac","Webact","Dions","Ps"': {0: ',,,,"Numsearching","Numsearchingbusiness","Numcatprod","Numview","Numviewed","Numviewed2","Numaction","Numwebsite","Numreques","Numcall"',
  1: 'Nora,"Ora","Sgo, Mp, 2000",,111,44,33,121,1232,53411,4,5,,3',
  2: 'mc11,"21 old","tjis that place, somewher, Netherlands, 2434",,3245,325,52454,3432,243,4353,343,23,23,18'}}
```

I have tried this so far and a bit stuck:

```
disc = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/blank/blank.csv',delimiter='",')
```

Sample of csv:
[csv sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18VKoj3r3mymI7ym63PN5QPoD5UNJVpJ5)

Comment: Who did that to your poor csv data? this is horrible? can you fix it at the source?  This looks like `','` seperated and `'"'` quoted for strings - but the part that makes this a dictionary makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: @PatrickArtner unfortunately I cannot

Comment: Either I don't understand something in the question or the default behavior of the built-in module csv is already handling your case. 
`import csv
with open('data.csv', newline='') as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in reader:
        # Do something with the data
`

Comment: @Pagefault If i use ',' as a delimiter it reads the entire first row as 1 column as opposed to separating each item to a column

Comment: I correct myself - it looks like a bad case of scraped data. No idea how to fix that. Good look.

Comment: data looks like some JSON file but with incorrect quotes.

Comment: @furas its a csv, I read the file using read_csv and converted a sample to a dictionary to create a reproducible example

Comment: can you show the raw csv? It's hard to understand what exactly is wrong from the dictionary (clearly something is wrong, but I don't know what).

Comment: I though you have this directly in csv. If you have it in dictionary then you can use `split(",")` to change strings into lists and it will looks amost as DataFrame.

Comment: @Eric Just added a link to a sample of the csv

Comment: The problem with your csv file is that every single line starts and ends with a `"` can you simply preprocess the file to remove those starting and ending `"` characters? The rest should be easily readable by csv readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use normal functions to remove `"` in every line on both ends, and I convert two `""` into single `"`

This way I get CSV which I can load with `read_csv()`

```
f1 = open('Sample - Sheet1.csv')
f2 = open('temp.csv', 'w')
for row in f1:
    row = row.strip() # remove "\n"
    row = row[1:-1] # remove " on both ends
    row = row.replace('""', '"') # conver "" into "
    f2.write(row + '\n')
f2.close()
f1.close()

df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

print(len(df.columns))
print(df)
```

---

Another method: read it as CSV and save as normal string

```
import csv

f1 = open('Sample - Sheet1.csv')
f2 = open('temp.csv', 'w')

reader = csv.reader(f1)
for row in reader:
    f2.write(row[0] + '\n')

f2.close()
f1.close()


df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

print(len(df.columns))
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, may I ask why you had to remove " on both ends?

Comment: they makes pair and CSV thinks that it is one long string, so it read it as single column. Inside this string CSV uses double `""` to informa that it is not end/start of value but normal char inside string.